# Datadog - group by substring of logs

Tags: datadog

I am trying to create a "Top List" visualization in DataDog and I would like to graph my data which should be grouped by error code. This error code is a substring in logs. An example of a line in the log is given below. I have tried to group my data by message but this is not working, I would like to group my data by substring of the message. Can someone guide me on this?

> ...Server Error {"error":{"code":1001,"type":"MATCH","message":"Invoke
>   failed: Failed...
>   ...Server Error {"error":{"code":2001,"type":"MATCH","message":"Invoke
>   failed: Failed...

Currently I get the visualization as follows

```
1.0 .....error:{"code":1001.....
1.0 .....error:{"code":1001.....
1.0 .....error:{"code":2001.....
```

1.0 is the number of occurrence

Rather I want the visualization as follows

```
2.0 .....error:{"code":1001.....
1.0 .....error:{"code":2001.....
```

2.0 will be total 2 occurrences of error 1001 and 1.0 will be the occurrences of error 2001

Answer (score 4):

**First** you'll want to make sure your logs are well structured (which you can control in [Datadog's processing pipelines](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/)). Effectively you'll want to parse out the "code" values into some "error code" attribute.

If your log events are in this format...

```
2020-01-01 12:10:10 myservername - Server Error {"error":{"code":1001,"type":"MATCH","message":"Invoke failed: Failed"}}
```

...Then all you need is a fairly simple grok parser rule, thanks to the "json" filter function. Something like this would get you where you want (note the `%{data::json}` part, that's what parses the in-log JSON).

```
myrulename %{date("yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM:ss"):timestamp} %{notSpace:hostname} - Server Error %{data::json}
```

Once you've configured this, your logs will also have an attribute called "error.code" with a value of `2001` or `1001` or whatever.

**Second** you'll want to [create a facet](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/?tab=logsearch#setup) for that new `error.code` attribute so that you can [make toplist / timeseries / etc. graphs grouped out by your "error code" facet](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/analytics/?tab=timeseries).

Comment: The actual format of the log is given below  
Feb 01 05:34:01 ip-1-2-3-4 db: {"@message":"GMS Error {\"error\":{\"code\":9001,\"type\":\"GMS_INTERNAL\",\"message\":\"Invoke failed: same state in database detected, please try again\",\"details\":null}} UniqueNonce: 1582608840282 LID: {\"Batch\":[\"0487\",\"1361\",\"392d\",\"8d95\"],\"Override\":0}","@timestamp":"2020-02-01T05:34:01.314Z","@fields":{"grpID":"fBJSON","logID":"x0074","component":"SMS","level":"error"}}
I have tried your suggestion but I was unable to extract error.code. Are we supposed to use kv filter? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: oh, so in this example, the log contains JSON, but inside that JSON it looks like you have a field ("@message") whose content is a string with some JSON-looking content. You _might_ be able to parse that out completely, but for that you may want to get help from Datadog support.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get some help from them. Will update if I get some solution

Comment: Ah a Facet... I could not figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: @stephenlechner what if my logs are NOT structured? can I run a adhoc query or something?